# Force a field to be an object type

Tags: python, type-conversion, dtype

I'm reading in two CSVs, one with data and the other to carry forward the data types from another notebook.

I'm using datatypes to filter numeric vs categorical - all fields are numeric. I'll be dropping and adding columns pretty often so a static list isn't a great alternative.

At one point this code #would# set to object, but for some reason my notebook has become increasingly more restrictive. For example on the same dataset I now have to use .info(verbose=True, null_count=True) where before I only needed .info().

dtypes csv looks like

| Column | Dtype |
| --- | --- |
| field1 | float64 |
| field2 | float64 |
| field3 | int64 |
| field4 | object |

Read in code:

```
for rows, cols in data_types.iterrows():
    if data_types.iloc[rows].Dtype == 'int64':
        train_test_df[cols[0]] = train_test_df[cols[0]].astype(np.int64)
    elif data_types.iloc[rows].Dtype == 'float64':
        train_test_df[cols[0]] = train_test_df[cols[0]].astype(float)
    elif data_types.iloc[rows].Dtype == 'object':
        train_test_df[cols[0]] = train_test_df[cols[0]].astype(object)
```

later I need to split this out into numeric and catagorical features.

```
    categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include = ["object"]).columns
    numeric_features = df.select_dtypes(exclude = ["object"]).columns
```

Tried using the complex data type but sklearn PCA doesn't like that dtype.

Also tried setting the numeric to string, but that quickly got me into trouble as well.

Any thoughts on an alternative dtype or approach that would allow me the flexibility to drop and re-add columns without a bunch of overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this, but it's janky and I'm still not sure why the code can

1. See that the row == object (i.e. the conditional fires correctly)
2. Work with exact same code (updating the df name) in a separate code cell (i.e. the code in the conditional performs as expected)

The approach is appending a list for all objects and setting it later in the cell

```
# load cleaned data from earlier notebook (exported to csv)

train_test_df = pd.read_csv('train_test_cleaned_w_added_features_TRIMMED.csv', header = 0)
train_test_df = train_test_df.iloc[:,1:].drop(index=0,axis=1)

# reset datatypes to match earlier notebook (exported to csv)

data_types = pd.read_csv('dtypes_TRIMMED.csv', names = ['Column',"Dtype"])

cat = []
for rows, cols in data_types.iterrows():
    if data_types.iloc[rows].Dtype == 'object':

        #insert janky workaround here
        cat.append(data_types.iloc[rows].Column)
    elif data_types.iloc[rows].Dtype == 'int64':
        train_test_df[cols[0]] = train_test_df[cols[0]].astype(np.int64)
    elif data_types.iloc[rows].Dtype == 'float64':
        train_test_df[cols[0]] = train_test_df[cols[0]].astype(float)

train_test_df = train_test_df.reset_index(drop=True)

#execute janky workaround 
train_test_df[cat] = train_test_df[cat].astype(object)
```